# VIM: set filetype=txt for every new file [No Name]

Tags: vim, default, new-operator, file-type

I tried all possible things to let vim set filetype to 'txt' to all new files I create (in a new tab) but it doesn't work.

This is p.e. what I've read on the web a few times:
`au BufRead,BufNewFile *.txt setlocal ft=txt`
(to put in _vimrc)
However it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You may want to use Vim's `text` filetype instead of your `txt` filetype. The `text` filetype was added in Vim 7.3.388 (2011-12-30).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The following line, added to your `.vimrc`, will set the `filetype` to `text` if it is not already set.

```
autocmd BufEnter * if &filetype == "" | setlocal ft=text | endif
```

Comment: The issue is that if I create a new file, and then save it as `test.py`, the filetype will remain `txt`. How can I make sure that a new file is of type `txt` unless it is explicitly saved as another type?

Comment: @charlax: I think using `BufWrite` (or `BufWritePost`) instead of `BufEnter` would ensure the filetype is only set on save, instead of on load.

Answer (score 5):

All files are considered plain text unless you have file-type detection turned on or explicitly set the file-type. However, Vim lets you set the file-type to any old text, so are you absolutely sure it is not working?

```
:set filetype=banana
:set filetype?
  filetype=banana
```

Setting the filetype is not going to have any noticable effect unless there is a corresponding file in the `ftplugin` Vim directory and Vim does not ship with a `txt.vim` file-type file. You could, of couse, add a `txt.vim` here but I am not sure what this will gain you over default settings — what special behaviour would you want for text files that you would not want for the default behaviour?

(If you want syntax highlighting (whatever that may mean for text file!) then you will also have to create a `txt.vim` file in the `syntax` Vim directory.)

What effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Paul, Yes, I have a txt.vim in the syntax directory. Do I have to put a file in ftplugin wich set ft=text for new files?

Comment: No, the syntax setting will be automatic (see `syntax/syntax.vim`) *providing* the automatic file-type detection succeeds. So I am guessing the syntax is failing because of the missing `ftplugin\txt.vim` — try adding a blank one. (Also, make sure you have syntax turned on: `syntax on` in your `.vimrc`/`_vimrc`.)

Comment: @Remonn: having said all that, I have just tried your `au` command and the syntax is being set correctly to `txt` even without `ftplugin\txt.vim`. My best guess now is that you do not have syntax turned on in your `.vimrc`.

Comment: @Remonn: OK, I've copied `syntax/cs.vim` to `syntax/txt.vim`, reopened Vim, run in your `au` command then opened a `.txt` file and the syntax is working perfectly. So definitely leaning towards `syntax on` not featuring in your `.vimrc`. You can confirm this by running `:syntax on` whilst in the editor.

Comment: @Paul, If I set ft=text the syntax is visible in text files. But the problem is that Vim doesn't set the (new, not saved) No Name file to ft=text.   Paul, where did you put the the line "au bufread....."?

Comment: For my tests, I put the `au` line in ex mode directly. This is equivalent to it being loaded from `.vimrc`. The problem is you are creating a new file without an extension so it's not hitting the file type detection rules. Either save the file with the `.txt` extension after creating or create your new files with a name, e.g. `new fred.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually way simpler than all this. Just put this as one of the first lines in your `.vimrc`.

```
set ft=txt
```

Whenever opening a new file, the filetype will be set to txt. But if you open a file with an known existing type it will still be overridden no problem.

Comment: it does so only for the No Name tab at VIM startup (and no syntax is shown till I save and reload the file). The new buffers (tabs) are not set to ft=txt.

Comment: Oops, good point. Curt Nelson's answer is the right way to do it.