# Syntax highlighting in Bash vi-input mode

Tags: bash, vim, vi

If I enable bash's input mode using `set -o vi`, then press <kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by <kbd>v</kbd>, I get a vi window which allows me to edit a temporary file which is executed once I leave. In that window I would like to enjoy Vim syntax highlighting for Bash scripts. It doesn't suffice to execute `:syntax enable`. The problem might be related to the fact that the temporary file has no `.sh` ending nor a `#!/bin/bash` head which could be used to determine the filetype.

Comment: What does `echo $EDITOR` output? Might be that you are actually calling `vi` or `vim` in compatible mode instead of `vim`. `vim` can usually pick up the filetype from heuristics like the shebang line.

Comment: would this solution be applicable?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487338/vim-set-filetype-txt-for-every-new-file-no-name  Essentially it sets the filetype to a default if one isn't detected.

Comment: _The problem might be related to the fact that the temporary file has no .sh ending_ Heh, you may have answered your own question....

Comment: Sometimes identifying the problem doesn't render its solution trivial...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to your `.vimrc`

```
if expand('%:t') =~?'bash-fc-\d\+'
  setfiletype sh
endif
```

the temporary files are of the form `bash-fc-3537253897`, so the regex matches if the file begins with `bash-fc-` and applies the filetype.

Answer (score 8):

I'd use the shorter formulation:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile bash-fc-* set filetype=sh
```

I believe this type of autocmd is the canonical way to handle filetype assignments (at least, my .vimrc has a number of them).

@Eric Fortis, please chime in or correct me if there's a reason you did it differently.